# Как создать и прочитать cookie через http на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, cookie, https

День добрый!
Интересует вопрос, можно ли создать и читать файлы куки не имея `SSl` сертификата, то есть `HTTPS` соединения? Пробовал делать так:

```
document.cookie = "Hello=World";
```

Но куки в браузере не появлялись. Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!
И возможно ли как то создавать куки, если html файл локальный?

Comment: как проверялось, что куки не появились?

Comment: смотрелись все куки на этом сайте

Comment: @ZeroBone, это https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie читали?

Comment: @ZeroBone, как именно смотрелись?

Comment: читал, не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Странно что у вас не работает, т.к. у меня команды `document.cookie = "username=John Doe";` и `document.cookie` работают нормально:

[image: создаем куку]

[image: получаем все куки]

Возможно есть какиенибудь ограничения в той среде, где вы работаете/проверяете? Время жизни кук например. Так же следует учитывать что куки использует время сервера (может отличаться от времени клиента).

Comment: Что-то у меня сомнения возникают, что js использует время сервера для установки кук в браузер.

Comment: @Visman Разумное замечание, но я просто привёл пример для размышления над проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему основной вопрос следующий:

> И возможно ли как то создавать куки, если html файл локальный?

Ответ на данный вопрос зависит от браузера. Например, в *Chrome* - по умолчанию отключена возможность использовать *cookies* для локальных файлов. Но данную настройку можно выключить воспользовавшись флагом: *--enable-file-cookies*

Для обратного примера: в браузере EDGE - приведенный код в вопросе работает и для локального файла.

В остальном код приведенный в вопрос вполне рабочий